# while JSON.parse(data) shows "b is undefined" in firefox

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-4

My controller, send the json object to View.

```
 public ActionResult GetFormsByCategory(string ParentFormCategoryID)
    {
        JavaScriptSerializer javaScriptSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        List<Forms> FormsList=null;
        try
        {
            FormsList = some data;
        }
        catch (Exception ep)
        {
            //error log
        }

        return Json(javaScriptSerializer.Serialize(FormsList),JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
```

and my ajax call, its success, but while operating on the json object it show b is undefined.

```
    $.ajax({
                url: '.url', //Target URL for JSON file
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                async: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    var rs = JSON.parse(data);
                    var FormList = "<ul style='list-style:none;display:block;' class='sub-list-forms'>";
                    $.each((rs), function (FormID, ViewName) {
                        //alert(ViewName);
                        FormList += "<li id='" + FormID + "'>" + ViewName + "</li><li>Reports</li>";
                    });
                    FormList += "</ul>";
                    $(this).append(FormList);
                },
                error: function (xhr, status) {
                    console.log(status);
                }
            });
```

I tried many options but all in vain..

Any help...?

Answer (score 0):

Firs of all you don't have to use `JavaScriptSerializer` because when you use `return Json(FormsList,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`it will automatically serialize your list. But your main issue here is that when you use  `dataType: 'json'` the response is converted automatically to JSON so you don't have to use `var rs = JSON.parse(data);`

If I summarize:

Controller:

```
    public ActionResult GetFormsByCategory(string ParentFormCategoryID)
    {
        List<Forms> FormsList=null;
        try
        {
            FormsList = some data;
        }
        catch (Exception ep)
        {
            //error log
        }

        return Json(FormsList,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
```

Ajax:

```
$.ajax({
                url: '.url', //Target URL for JSON file
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                async: false,
                success: function (data) {

                    var FormList = "<ul style='list-style:none;display:block;' class='sub-list-forms'>";
                    $.each((data), function (FormID, ViewName) {
                        //alert(ViewName);
                        FormList += "<li id='" + FormID + "'>" + ViewName + "</li><li>Reports</li>";
                    });
                    FormList += "</ul>";
                    $(this).append(FormList);
                },
                error: function (xhr, status) {
                    console.log(status);
                }
            });
```

- And by the way initializing `FormsList` to a null could cause some issues as well, in case you have an exception in your controller - you will be serializing a `null` and according to JQuery ajax help page:

> The JSON data is parsed in a strict manner; any malformed JSON is
>   rejected and a parse error is thrown. As of jQuery 1.9, an empty
>   response is also rejected; the server should return a response of null
>   or {} instead.

So in this case you better return a null instead of

`return Json(FormsList,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`